# 403 error when accessing an external image URL on an internal website

Tags: javascript, internals

I've been working on this internal web app that allows the users to click on a button to see an image. Pretty straight forward.

```
<img id="swatchimage" width="600" height="600" src="" />
```

The image needs to be linked from an external website. The piece of javascript that does that is:

```
$("#swatchimage").attr("src", fileURL);
```

One of the URLs look like this:

[image]

If you try to access the image above in a browser it works without a problem.
When accessing it from the internal app ( IP: 192.168.110.15 ) then the server returns 403 error.

The same files are used in the main website, so I don't think it's about the hot linking protection (which i tried to disable too, to no avail).

Is there some restriction that I'm not aware of when linking these kind of resources?

Comment: Is the internal IP behind a firewall, which blocks requests to this CDN URL?

Comment: I wish it were. But as I said, if I try to access it directly in the website it works.

Comment: Maybe it's because CORS.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem:

The server (cdn.palmcentre.co.uk) is not sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response, so you can't use JavaScript to fetch it.

However, this is not a `403`. Here's a screenshot of the error I get:

[image: Me trying to fetch the image using JS]

Also, what you're trying to do is **not** to fetch the image, but modify the `src` attribute of an `<image>` element, which should be allowed.

This makes me think that the error you're getting is because jQuery is trying to fetch the image, and failing, but I'm not sure.

Try doing this instead:

```
document.getElementById("#swatchimage").src = fileURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have found the solution.

It was puzzling indeed, because i knew that CORS would not be at play here. It was just another image URL that was requested from an HTML tag. So it shouldn't have behaved in such way.

Notwithstanding the help received, for which I am grateful, it seems that the issue was in fact a hot linking protection that was in place.

But it was not from the server itself or from the script but rather from the CloudFlare cache itself.